# Should I be worried about getting struck by lightning?

Tags: made-in-abyss-binary-star

In the Upland Wasteland on the 2nd Layer there are lightning strikes that occur every few seconds. I've had some close calls where a bolt hit the ground near me, but I haven't seen it hit me or an enemy. Is it possible to get struck by lightning?

[image: Lightning strike]
<sub>Screenshot from [Hikikomori Gaming (1:21:08)](https://youtu.be/ckuDBQzly2A?t=4863)</sub>